# PreparedStatement with Data Type Casting in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Is there a way in groovy to specify datatype in groovy as like in Java for `PreparedStatement` as below?

```
PreparedStatement ps = new PreparedStatement("<STATEMENT>");
ps.setDate("date_column", new Date());
```

Comment: are you using grails ??

Comment: No. Just groovy syntax

Comment: @DON : you can use same java code in groovy as well

Comment: Yes But I have generic `DB` Object so I can't use Java one to mention database connection string and credentials

Comment: Maybe you could add then the code or further hints, what you DB is.  It seems that your problem arises from that?